# Remove one word out of two same word from url

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

When I am filter data first its URL like be this type

```
"http://localhost/computers?specs=Category:intel!!0!!".
```

But when I am filtering second time its URL would be like this

```
"http://localhost/computers??specs=Category:intel!!0!!".
```

So just I want to do that if I filter second time remove '??' (question mark) one out of two. Here is the code
`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var currURL = window.location.href;

                String.prototype.endsWith = function (currURL) {
                    var d = this.length - currURL.length;
                    return d >= 0 && this.lastIndexOf(currURL) === d;
                };
</script>
```

`removing trailing '?' from url if any

Comment: A better solution would be to not put the second `?` in the URL in the first place. How is the URL being generated?

Comment: Url is generated through our product. For ex : http://localhost/ (this is our localhost and) computers?specs=Category:intel!!0!! (this is our product and category). so can we remove the '?' after the "var currURL = window.location.href;" line if yes then please suggest me.

Comment: As Rory said, it is better to not put second `?` in the first place. But if you have to remove it later, you can try `var currURL = window.location.href; window.location.href = currURL.split("??").join("?");`

Comment: Thanks Alex. But this one I try but it is not working. Any other way?

Comment: @karan, why you allow to add second time same filter?

Comment: Bcos first time I remove the category filter(which one I selected) and second time I think that I want to add the same category filter (which one I removed). So that's y, I would allow the second time same filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

Url=url.replace("??",?)

Comment: This one also I try but still the same issue